# Sign Databases on Domino server side

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I have a need to sign database(s) on server-side using Java (preferably). I tried sign method

```
Database.sign()
```

however it only works if you run it on workstation (doesn't work if code runs on server). I have also checked if any command for console to send them via

```
session.SendConsoleCommand
```

I wonder if there is something I miss and it's possible to sign databases?

I am considering now to update every design element in database instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the Files panel in Domino administrator, right-click on a database. You will see "Sign" as an option on the context menu. You can also sign multiple databases by right-clicking on a folder, or by using a combination of shift-click and control-click to highlight a multi-selection and then right-clicking.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm looking for a programmatic way. I will udpdate question a bit. Sorry If I was not clear.

Comment: Ah. I understand. Unfortunately, AFAIK, code signing is client side feature.  My guess is that there's a security reason (or two, or three...) why they wouldn't want to allow it to execute on the server side.

Comment: but basically there is kind of (not sure if that is equivalent) workaround: iterate NotesNoteCollection, sign & save every design document.

Comment: Does that work from a server-sde agent? It would obviously have to sign using the server id for that. What if the agent is not signed by the same server id? It seems to me like allowing an agent permission to sign with the server id ought to require some extra permissions on top of just having Designer access to the database.

Comment: > What if the agent is not signed by the same server id? 
In my case it's Domino Java addin that loads together with Domino (and it runs under domino id, thus there is no issues with security).